# Unity Error: an error occurred while resolving packages: one or more packages could not be added to the local file system unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a project on version 2021.3.8f1 and in any project an error occurs: error

how can I solve it? I already tried everything: `delete manifest.json`, `delete package.lock.json`, reset all packages, delete Library folder, update all packages to latest version in package manager and still nothing. Maybe I should manually download all packages?

Comment: Does the path to your project have a space or and non-ASCII characters in it? It's been a problem in the past, dunno if they fixed it, but maybe worth a shot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed that Retired Ninja's answer worked for me. After spending hours working on every other possible solution, I deleted the project and created a new one with only letters in the project name, and all errors went away.